# Integers are formatted incorrectly when cross-compiling to armv5te

Tags: rust, cross-compiling

When compiling the following program on my computer, it outputs the expected value:

```
fn main() {
    let number = 42;
    println!("number is {}", number);
}
```

> number is 42

When cross-compiled for armv5te and run on the target, it outputs the following result:

> number is 14

I believe that the implementation of `Display` for `i32` is not working as expected. In particular, it seems that the characters printed are taken at the wrong index in the following array (found in [libcore/fmt/num.rs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/2c6933acc/src/libcore/fmt/num.rs#L186-L191)):

```
const DEC_DIGITS_LUT: &'static[u8] =
    b"0001020304050607080910111213141516171819\
      2021222324252627282930313233343536373839\
      4041424344454647484950515253545556575859\
      6061626364656667686970717273747576777879\
      8081828384858687888990919293949596979899";
```

The two digits displayed are taken on the table at an offset of 1 byte to the left compared with the right place. I verified this hypothesis by testing with some other numbers (10 -> 91, 11 -> 01 for instance).

Other formats (`{:b}`, `{:o}`, `{:x}`) all give the expected result on my computer and on the target.

---

I am using a self compiled version of Rust (1.13.0, 2c6933acc 2016-11-07) for the successful test on my computer and the unsuccessful one on my ARM device. Here is the diff of the modifications I had to do:

```
diff --git a/mk/cfg/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi.mk b/mk/cfg/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi.mk
index f66ad04..b9e4157 100644
--- a/mk/cfg/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi.mk
+++ b/mk/cfg/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi.mk
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 # arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi configuration
-CROSS_PREFIX_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi=arm-linux-gnueabi-
+CROSS_PREFIX_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi=arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi-
 CC_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi=gcc
 CXX_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi=g++
 CPP_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi=gcc -E
@@ -8,8 +8,8 @@ CFG_LIB_NAME_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi=lib$(1).so
 CFG_STATIC_LIB_NAME_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi=lib$(1).a
 CFG_LIB_GLOB_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi=lib$(1)-*.so
 CFG_LIB_DSYM_GLOB_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi=lib$(1)-*.dylib.dSYM
-CFG_JEMALLOC_CFLAGS_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi := -Darm -mfloat-abi=soft $(CFLAGS) -march=armv6 -marm
-CFG_GCCISH_CFLAGS_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi := -Wall -g -fPIC -Darm -mfloat-abi=soft $(CFLAGS) -march=armv6 -marm
+CFG_JEMALLOC_CFLAGS_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi := -Darm -mfloat-abi=soft $(CFLAGS) -fno-stack-protector -march=armv5te -mtune=arm926ej-s
+CFG_GCCISH_CFLAGS_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi := -Wall -g -fPIC -Darm -mfloat-abi=soft $(CFLAGS) -fno-stack-protector -march=armv5te -mtune=arm926ej-s
 CFG_GCCISH_CXXFLAGS_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi := -fno-rtti $(CXXFLAGS)
 CFG_GCCISH_LINK_FLAGS_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi := -shared -fPIC -g
 CFG_GCCISH_DEF_FLAG_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi := -Wl,--export-dynamic,--dynamic-list=
diff --git a/src/librustc_back/target/arm_unknown_linux_gnueabi.rs b/src/librustc_back/target/arm_unknown_linux_gnueabi.rs
index e666a84..8af2596 100644
--- a/src/librustc_back/target/arm_unknown_linux_gnueabi.rs
+++ b/src/librustc_back/target/arm_unknown_linux_gnueabi.rs
@@ -24,7 +24,7 @@ pub fn target() -> TargetResult {
 target_vendor: "unknown".to_string(),

 options: TargetOptions {
-            features: "+v6".to_string(),
+            features: "+v5te".to_string(),
 .. base
 },
 })
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging on the target? Stepping into the formatting code to check the pointer & index could be very informative.

Comment: I agree with you @MatthieuM. but I am new to rust and I don't know how I can do that. What can I use to debug the code on my target ?

Comment: Rust creates normal binaries, so use your normal debugging tools such as GDB or LLDB.

Comment: Alignment maybe? If the array starts on an odd address and it reads 16-bit values, the last address bit could be ignored on the read, i.e. it would read from the even address one lower.

Comment: Is that for the LEGO Mindstorms EV3?

Comment: You were right @starblue, I disassembled the code using `gdb` only to find out that the lookup table is at an odd address (0x2a057bc3 in my case), the code attempts to load two bytes at once at 0x2a057c17, which is the correct location in the lookup table, but uses an `LDRH` instruction to do so. in the [ARM spec](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka15414.html) I can see that for ARM9, `LDRH` and `STRH` require the address to be 2-byte aligned.

Comment: I think that I probably missed something when compiling rust. Maybe it is the configuration for LLVM ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this problem!
The problem was that LLVM was not properly configured and was generating code performing unaligned accesses. To fix this, I added the `strict-align` feature flag in src/librustc_back/target/arm_unknown_linux_gnueabi.rs
Here is the final diff with all the modifications I had to do:

```
diff --git a/mk/cfg/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi.mk b/mk/cfg/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi.mk
index f66ad04..b9e4157 100644
--- a/mk/cfg/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi.mk
+++ b/mk/cfg/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi.mk
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 # arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi configuration
-CROSS_PREFIX_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi=arm-linux-gnueabi-
+CROSS_PREFIX_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi=arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi-
 CC_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi=gcc
 CXX_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi=g++
 CPP_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi=gcc -E
@@ -8,8 +8,8 @@ CFG_LIB_NAME_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi=lib$(1).so
 CFG_STATIC_LIB_NAME_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi=lib$(1).a
 CFG_LIB_GLOB_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi=lib$(1)-*.so
 CFG_LIB_DSYM_GLOB_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi=lib$(1)-*.dylib.dSYM
-CFG_JEMALLOC_CFLAGS_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi := -D__arm__ -mfloat-abi=soft $(CFLAGS) -march=armv6 -marm
-CFG_GCCISH_CFLAGS_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi := -Wall -g -fPIC -D__arm__ -mfloat-abi=soft $(CFLAGS) -march=armv6 -marm
+CFG_JEMALLOC_CFLAGS_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi := -D__arm__ -mfloat-abi=soft $(CFLAGS) -fno-stack-protector -march=armv5te -mtune=arm926ej-s
+CFG_GCCISH_CFLAGS_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi := -Wall -g -fPIC -D__arm__ -mfloat-abi=soft $(CFLAGS) -fno-stack-protector -march=armv5te -mtune=arm926ej-s
 CFG_GCCISH_CXXFLAGS_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi := -fno-rtti $(CXXFLAGS)
 CFG_GCCISH_LINK_FLAGS_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi := -shared -fPIC -g
 CFG_GCCISH_DEF_FLAG_arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi := -Wl,--export-dynamic,--dynamic-list=
diff --git a/src/librustc_back/target/arm_unknown_linux_gnueabi.rs b/src/librustc_back/target/arm_unknown_linux_gnueabi.rs
index e666a84..551bba0 100644
--- a/src/librustc_back/target/arm_unknown_linux_gnueabi.rs
+++ b/src/librustc_back/target/arm_unknown_linux_gnueabi.rs
@@ -24,7 +24,7 @@ pub fn target() -> TargetResult {
         target_vendor: "unknown".to_string(),

         options: TargetOptions {
-            features: "+v6".to_string(),
+            features: "+v5te,+strict-align".to_string(),
             .. base
         },
     })
```